# Why is deleting huge number of files (small size on average) longer than single file (huge size)

Tags: windows

Let say I have 2 case of deleting files:

1. 150,000 files with size of 30 KB on average, the total size is 4 GB
   --> finished within an hour
2. single file with size of 8 GB
   --> finished in a snap

The file size in case 2 is larger than case 1
Why is deleting on case 1 took much longer time than case 2 ?

Comment: it would be great if someone can provide visual explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since somebody asked for a *visual explanation* (roughly speaking and exaggerating):

[(Click to see the full-size image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyAPL.png)

[image: File deletion]

Answer (score 2):

Deleting every file includes updates to directory metadata (i.e. place where information about file is stored) and (generally) updates to free space bitmap. Each of 150,000 files is one operation on metadata that can be all around the disk.

Deleting single file, no matter the size, is change to single metadata entry.

So, in first case, you are actually doing 150,000 more operations than in second one.

Comment: This is not a fair comparison because the second case may require significantly more operations to the free space tracking.

Comment: Yes, second case can (and will) include many more updates to free space bitmap but, compared to number of file entry updates we might as well ignore it. Since whole bitmap is generally contained in one area of disk, even in given case we are speaking just about single update of 250 KB (8 GB file, 4 KB sector). Real-life numbers depend on so many factors, file system type and sector size being most important ones...

Comment: Just to give some (ROUGH) math. Each 30 KB file will include updates to file entry (4 KB write) + update to free space bitmap (4 KB write). For 150,000 files that is about 1 GB of writes spread all across the disk. In 8 GB file case, this will be one file entry update (4 KB) + free space bitmap update (250 KB). Difference is huge, even without taking into account need to actually read data before write happens. And yes, smart disk caching will tend to improve numbers a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Case 1 requires many, many more directory operations. Each file is individually deleted which requires removing it from the directory it is in.

Deleting 150,000 files requires finding each file in the directory structure and then removing that file from the directory, maintaining the organization of the directory structure in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Each file is saved to a different section on your hdd platter. Files can also be split up so more files + more fragments = more time. A larger file will have fewer fragments and the HDD will spend less time finding them.

Comment: Fragments of a file don't need to be accessed when the file is deleted.

Comment: It still needs to find the location on the disk to delete it

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that, but regardless, it's not accessing the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a file, most operating systems will merely mark its directory entry as unused, to be later replaced with the directory entry to another file (in addition to marking the space it occupied on disk as free).

It's not actually going through all the data in the file and removing it, this is why undelete utilities work.